# VERY HARD Collision Questions, (Further Maths A Level)

Tags: classical-mechanics, collision-detection

[Ques](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHIkq.png)

I've attached the question using the link since it would be too hard to format myself.

Essentially, What i've done so far is said;

- From start to wall 1, the time is $\frac{d}{u}$
- From Wall 1 to Wall 2, the time is $\frac{9}{2u}$
- From Wall 2 to Start, the time is $\frac{3-d}{u}$

But when i add them together i do not get the desired result, im not quite sure where ive gone wrong

Comment: If a Maths question is VERY HARD for a normal mathematics practitioner, it probably belongs here: https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @UtkarshGupta _Very hard_ is relative to an individual's ability. This question does _not_ belong on MathOverflow.

Comment: Hint: look closely at the time from Wall 2 to Start. The particle should be slowing down even more.

Comment: I got the speed of the particle after first bounce to be 2/3 u,

Comment: @nickgard but after the second bounce for some reason i got the speed to be U?

Comment: The first speed is $u$. The second speed in ${2 \over 3} u$. The third speed is $({2 \over 3})^2$. Your computations above are wrong.

Comment: Every time it hits a wall the speed drops by the given factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the original velocity in the third segment where you should have used $\frac23\cdot\frac23\cdot u$.